# Magento2 - trying to update module template file not working

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, overrides

Template path hint is showing below given path for that file which i want to overwrite.

```
/home/tunersto/public_html/mysite.com/app/code/Nwdthemes/Revslider/view/frontend/templates/revslider.phtml
```

And i create below given directory & files in my current active theme.

```
/public_html/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/Nwdthemes_Revslider/template/revslider.phtml
```

but file did not get overwrited. Even i cleared cache and deploy static content. Let me know if i left something. i am quite new in magento2 world

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Instead of `/Nwdthemes_Revslider/template/revslider.phtml` use `/Nwdthemes_Revslider/templates/revslider.phtml` on last one

Comment: Thanks it works. i dont know how i did that mistake. Even i was care about the "s" of template folder and i think forget to change and suppose i was change it.  thank you.

Comment: ankit you answer first for this question so if you want give to answer i will accept it as solve. let me know please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change

From

```
/public_html/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/Nwdthemes_Revslider/template/revslider.phtml
```

To

```
/public_html/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/Nwdthemes_Revslider/templates/revslider.phtml
```

It's typo error for Folder Name from `template` to `templates` then will solve your issue.

Comment: hi, i have 1 another issue but. it does not let me post another question. stack exchange will allow post another question after 40 min

Comment: When u post just update will try to help. Thanks. Upvote if u can

Comment: p[lease cehck issue

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150879/automatic-generation-of-dir-files-under-pub-static-not-working

Answer (score 0):

There is a spelling mistake in your folder name. It should be `templates` and not `template`. Try keeping your file at this path:

```
/public_html/mysite.com/app/design/frontend/Etheme/yourstore/Nwdthemes_Revslider/templates/revslider.phtml
```

Clear `var/cache`, `var/generation`, `var/view_preprocessed` and check.

If the changes still don't reflect then clear above folders, and clear `pub/static` then run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` and then check.

Hope this helps.