# automatic generation of dir/files under pub/static not working

Tags: magento2, development, htaccess, static-content, deploy

automatic generation of dir/files under pub/static not working. When i google about this find that i have to delete that file in which i did change and then run below given command.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

But there must be another way. because every time i cant run this command when change code in css file. And update css file under pub/static and upload final css file in last under theme and then run content is also not a solution.

i read on stack-overflow about .htaccess file must be under pub/static but that file also not work. it was removed so i add again file under `pub/static/.htaccess` But it does not work.

Comment: Please check for file permissions of folder 777 ?

Comment: I don't understand. You say that you edit some css file in `pub/static` and it is overwritten when you run the static content deploy command ?

Comment: @Marius i mean when i do any changing in example.css in a theme file and run eploy command nothing happen because first i need to that file from pub/static. so when i delete that file and run deploy command. updated css file is woprking means newly genrated file in pub/static have updated code

Comment: @Marius can you help me in my other question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150923/magento2-how-to-get-all-product-through-attribute-value-without-category

Comment: hi can you help me of this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/151482/magento2-custom-different-flat-shipping-charge-for-few-products

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two different scenarios:

1. developer mode

   - you should not run the command at all (more info: [Which compilation commands are needed in developer mode and when?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/107055/which-compilation-commands-are-needed-in-developer-mode-and-when) )
   - the original `pub/static/.htaccess` file is necessary
   - the webserver user must have permissions to create symlinks in `pub/static` (if you are on Windows, you have to set up permissions first because by default only administrators can create symlinks)
2. production mode

   - you have to run the deployment command after each change. Period.

Obviously you don't want to develop in production mode.

Comment: do i need to change any permission manually for "symlinks" on Linux?

Comment: No, on Linux pub/static just needs normal write permissons. If `bin/magento` runs with a different user than the web server user, please refer to http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/prereq/file-system-perms.html for the correct permissions